# Automated Amazon CloudWatch Metric creation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

Had couple of questions on AWS:

1. Is there a way by which I can recreate/write AWS CloudWatch metrics to DynamoDB?
2. If an Amazon EC2 instance is deleted or if I change a VPC, I need to recreate all CloudWatch metrics manually every time. Is there a way by which I can automate CloudWatch metrics creation for every new VPC instance? Through Terraform, I can only create CloudWatch metric alarms, events and logs but not CloudWatch metrics (eg, EC2, RDS metrics etc).

Comment: Amazon EC2 and Amazon RDS automatically create metrics in Amazon CloudWatch. What do you mean by "automate CloudWatch metrics creation"? Are you talking about Custom Metrics?

Comment: My intention was to keep instance id as a variable so that every time I change my instance, I just want to update the id and my metrics gets created by its own. I could achieve it via AWS CLI and via Python script thereby writing it to dynamodb as well

Answer (score 0):

#1 I could achieve it via AWS CLI and via Python script thereby writing it to dynamodb as well. #2 is still open.